# Why $('*') doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the following jQuery code, I'd like to highlight the row including "z". Somehow, the $('*') doesn't work. If I modify it to $('li'), it will work.

```
<ul>
  <li>a b c</li>
  <li>x y z</li>
</ul>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function($) {
    var pattern = /z/i;
    $('*').filter(function() {
      return pattern.test($(this).text());
    }).wrap('<strong></strong>');
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: your console `Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'DIV' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'. `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` selects `html` node also, then you are trying to wrap that in a `strong` element which could be the problem.

In your console you should see an error like

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on
>   'Node': Nodes of type 'STRONG' may not be inserted inside nodes of
>   type '#document'.

```js
(function($) {
  var pattern = /z/i;
  var a = $('body *').filter(function() {
    return pattern.test($(this).text());
  }).wrap('<strong></strong>');
})(jQuery);
```

```css
strong {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>a b c</li>
  <li>x y z</li>
</ul>
```

Note: Still it won't give you the desired output since it will wrap all the ancestor elements also you can't wrap an `li` with `strong` element

---

So you can either limit the search only to the `li` like `ul li` or to use the text nodes for the comparison

```js
(function($) {
  var pattern = /z/i;
  var a = $('*').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && pattern.test(this.nodeValue);
  }).wrap('<strong></strong>');
})(jQuery);
```

```css
strong {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>a b c</li>
  <li>x y z</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text li only

```
  (function($) {
    var pattern = /z/i;
    $('*').find("ul li").filter(function(i,v) {
      return pattern.test($(this).text());
    }).wrap('<strong></strong>');
  })(jQuery);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/whgyaLwm/)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it requires these, try the following:

1. Select all
2. Add DOM [strong] (to * add strong)
3. In * add [strong] -->> 2. Repeat for [strong]....  <<-- Requires